# Use the chain rule to compute ∂z/∂x and ∂z/∂y for 2x^2+y^2+z^2=9. Where exactly do I use it and how?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use the chain rule to compute $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ for $2x^2+y^2+z^2=9$.

I got the following, however I don't think I'm using the chain rule.  Where exactly do I use it and how?

$\dfrac{d}{dy}$ $(2x^2+y^2+z^2)$ = $\dfrac{d}{dy}$ $(9)$.

$\dfrac{d}{dy}$$(2x^2) + $$\dfrac{d}{dy}$(y^2) + $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$(z^2)$ = $\dfrac{d}{dy}$(9)

0 + 2y + $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$(z^2)$ = 0

2y + $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$(2z) = 0

$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$(2z) = -2y

$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$= $\dfrac{-2y}{2z}$ = $\dfrac{-y}{z}$

$\dfrac{d}{dx}$ $(2x^2+y^2+z^2)$ = $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ $(9)$

2$\dfrac{d}{dx}$$(x^2)$+$\dfrac{d}{dx}$$(y^2)$+$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$(z^2)$=$\dfrac{d}{dx}$(9).

2(2x)+$\dfrac{d}{dx}$$(y^2)$+$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$(z^2)$=$\dfrac{d}{dx}$(9)

4x+ 0 + $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$(z^2)$ = 0

4x + $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$(2z) = 0

$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$(2z) = -4x

$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$= $\dfrac{-4x}{2z}$ = $\dfrac{-2x}{z}$

My answers of -y/z and -2x/z are correct, but how do I apply the chain rule to the problem.  I also want to apologize up front for the formatting, I just am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: `$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$` = $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$. `$\dfrac{df}{dx}$` = $\dfrac{df}{dx}$.  Use double `$`'s to get math centered on a new line `$$\dfrac{a}{b} = c^2$$` = $$\dfrac{a}{b} = c^2$$

Comment: My homework stated:  Use the chain rule to compute $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ for $2x^2+y^2+z^2=9$. @Fawad.

Comment: +1 For the effort on the edit, don't see why you where downvoted. As formatting goes, for example: `0 + 2y + $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$(z^2)$ = 0` only requires `$` at he beginning and at the end of a line, see: $0 + 2y + \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}(z^2) = 0$ looks better than 0 + 2y + $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$(z^2)$ = 0. To put in display mode, simply use double `$` at the beginning and the end of the line: `$$0 + 2y + \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}(z^2) = 0$$` renders as $$0 + 2y + \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}(z^2) = 0$$

Comment: For information about writing math on MSE see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Also, here is a very cool little tool called [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) where you can 
draw the symbol you are looking for and the system will tell you what the TeX command is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use implicit differentiation. The idea is that, suppose you can write $z = g(x,y)$. Then you can rewrite the equation about as $F(x,y, g(x,y)=z) = 0$ where $F = 2x^2+y^2+z^2-9$. To compute $z_x$ and $z_y$, we use the chain rule.

In computing these partials, we will assume $F_z \not = 0$. Thus, since $z = g(x,y)$, for a small neighborhood of the points $(x,y,g(x,y))$ we can choose a curve $c(t) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that:

\begin{align*} (x,y,g(x,y)) \in F( c(t)) \Rightarrow 0 &= \frac{d}{dt}(F \circ c)(t)\\&= \nabla F \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x,y,g(x,y) \\&= (F_x, F_y, F_z)  \cdot (1,0, g_x) \\& \Rightarrow F_x + F_z g_x 
=0 \\& \Rightarrow g_x=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = - \frac{F_x}{F_z} = - \frac{2x}{z} \end{align*}

I've given $F$ above, and so you have half the answer. Do a similar computation to derive $z_y$ i.e just replace $\partial/ \partial x$ with $\partial/ \partial y$.

Comment: How does implicit differentiation transfer over to the chain rule?

Comment: The is just the name given to the type of differentiation we must use to produce $z_x,z_y$. The term implicit here simply means we know $z$ is a function of $x,y$ and so instead of algebraically trying to write $z = g(x,y)$, we just say such a function $g$ exists. The rest should be clear.

Comment: If this answers your question, you can accept to close the question, otherwise, do you have any more questions?

Comment: My homework stated to use the chain rule to solve for this.  My question was specifically referring to the chain rule.  My question to you was regarding the chain rule specifically and how it transfers to the chain rule.  I have the answers to the question, however my homework specifically stated to use the chain rule.

Comment: I did use the chain rule, isn't $\frac{d}{dt} (f \circ c) = \nabla f \cdot c'$ the chain rule? I used that above.

Comment: is implicit differentiation the same as the chain rule?

Comment: You use the chain rule to do implicit differentiation as seen above.